# Calculating the hat matrix when 'n' is large (60000)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the 'hat matrix' in python. I am using the following formula. When the length of X is large (say 60,000) I am getting out of memory issues.
H = X*inv(X'X)*X'

Is there a computationally more efficient way of doing this? Snippet of the code is below

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(60000,1)
hat = X.dot(np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T))
```

Comment: I don't have any solution, but for starters have you considered that the ``hat`` matrix will be 28.8GB in size  if using float64 (``60_000**2 * 8 / 1e9``). Perhaps you could look at  using SciPy sparse matrices

Comment: Are you sure you need the matrix explicitly? One can usually solve a linear system without explicitly forming the object, e.g., by using [`np.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html?highlight=solve#numpy.linalg.solve).

Comment: I don't like to test memory errors, but if I tackled this I'd start evaluating it step by step, so as to get a clear idea of where the error arises.  In other words start with the `X.T.dot(X)`.  Then the `inv`, and so on.  But simply estimating the array size at each step may be enough.

Comment: There might be for particular kinds of matrix X, e.g. sparse.  You need to share all you know about X for people to be able to help. Bnaecker's question is very much to the point: do you really need all of the hat matrix? What for? If, for example, you just want the state vector you don't need to compute the hat matrix, and indeed are likely to lose accuracy by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to what was said in the comments, probably this is the intermediate result for some other computation.

You can abstract this in a custom class. Thanks to operator overriding you can implement use it very naturally.

Here I am giving you a class that allows you to take matrix slices of the result matrix, or to multiply by a vector on the left.

```py
class HatMatrix:
    def __init__(self, X):
        m,n = X.shape;
        self.X = X;
        assert m >= n;
    
    def __array__(self):
        X = self.X;
        return X @ np.linalg.inv(X.T.conj() @ X) @ X.T.conj()
    
    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        if not isinstance(indices, tuple):
            I = indices;
            J = slice(None,None);
        else:
            I,J = indices;
        X = self.X;
        XJ = np.atleast_2d(X[J,:]);
        XI = np.atleast_2d(X[I,:]);
        return XI @ np.linalg.inv(X.T.conj() @ X) @ XJ.T.conj()
    def __matmul__(self, v):
        X = self.X
        return (X @ np.linalg.inv(X.T.conj() @ X)) @ (X.T.conj() @ v)
```

Here is an example of how you can use it

```py
X = np.random.rand(60000,1)
hat = HatMatrix(X)
hat[0] # the first row
hat[30:40, 10:40] # a submatrix
hat[50000, 50000] # a single element
hat @ (X**4); # multiply hat by a 60000 x 1 vector
```

The above example runs in 5ms here.